# stuck on this screen "Sending analysis to the App Store"

Tags: xcode, app-store, uploading

Tried to upload two different apps but at the end get stuck on this screen "Sending analysis to the App Store".[image: Reference Image]

Comment: (1) Your ipa has a space in its name? Don't do that. (2) You're not using Bitcode are you?

Comment: 1) No space in the ipa 
2) Bitcode option checked

Comment: Yeah I would try unchecking Bitcode. It causes a lot of trouble in my experience.

Comment: I once tried this issue. End up my firewall is blocking some network packets. To workaround, I use the Transporter app to upload the App to App Store instead. Simple & Effective.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**FINALLY** - after wasting 4 complete days :)

Removing account from Xcode -> preference -> Accounts
and re-add it worked for me

Hopefully it'll work for you too...

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Solved my one too. Thanks 

Comment: March 2024 , works thx!

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time just due to slow connection or Apple server

Answer (score 0):

Easier solution than aceepted answer (may you cannot remove account):

Just create new certificates for your account..
from `Xcode -> preference -> Accounts -> select your team account -> press manage certificates press (+) to add development certificatte and ios destribution certificate..

then try again and your problem will be solved .

[image]